# VSCode and c++ compile_commands.json: ".h file not found" but can open it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In a work environment I'm forced to use the compile_commands.json which is generated by clang to provide Intellisense the information it needs. The project I have here actually compiles successfully from the commandline.

Yet intellisense does not work as header files are marked with:
"FILE_PATH.h file not found".

However rightclick and "go to definition" opens the header file without any issues. So Studio Code does obviously know where the file is.

My c_cpp_properties.json file looks as follows (and the paths are correct):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MyConfig",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/lib/ccache/clang++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "compileCommands": "/CORRECT_PATH_TO/compile_commands.json"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

What could possible issues be?

I have tried the hints from here like remaking the intellisense database but without success: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-recreate-the-intellisense-database

Is it normal that the compile_commands.json only mentions the .cpp files and not .h files?
Could this have something to do with the "Unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace." notification I get (and which I had to ignore so far)?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: It is normal that compile_commands.json is not using cpp files. Each compile_commands.json entry is for one file being compiled. You compile .cpp files, but not .h files.